# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null - Nothing seems to fix it

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I've looked at other stackoverflow questions and other website for answers.
They help but it still wont work and I don't know why.
Please tell me what I did wrong. Thank you!

I'm currently doing:

1. define global variables and run function in a window.onload function
2. Have Javascript after the main HTML part
3. Spell-checked the variable names

```js
window.onload = function() {
  window.level = 0;
  window.xp = 0;
  window.totalMoney = 0;
  window.clicks = 0;
  window.money = 0;
  window.max = 0;
  Up();
}

function UpLevel() {
  xp = totalMoney + 5 * clicks;
  level = Math.floor(0.5 * Math.log2(xp / 10 + 2));
  max = Math.floor(Math.pow(1.5, level) * 100) - 100;
}

function Up() {
  UpLevel();
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
  document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;
  document.getElementById("levelUp").innerHTML = Math.ceil(Math.pow(2, 2 * level + 2) * 10 - 20);
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
  document.getElementById("max").innerHTML = max;
}
```

```css
#fontA {
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#PosA {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#PosB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="fontA">
    <div id="PosA">
      Level: <label id="level" />
      <br/> XP: <label id="xp" /> / <label id="levelUp" />
      <br/>
      <br/> Clicks: <label id="clicks" />
    </div>
    <div id="PosB">
      $ <label id="money" />
      <br/> / <label id="max" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `window.xp = 0;`  `<label id="xp" />`  a variable cannot be both an integer and an element..

Comment: what r u saying i do? @Keith

Comment: @Keith No. That's not how it works.

Comment: @Razem it is how it works, creating an element with an id creates a global variable with that id,.. But it's also true what you said about the pair tag, so it's a mix of both really.. :)

Comment: @Keith It does create a global variable containing a reference to the element. But it doesn't prevent you from overriding its value. So this JS code is perfectly valid and those variables are set to 0. The only problem is with the HTML formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`<label>` is a pair tag. You have to write both opening and closing tags (`<label id="something"></label>`):

```
<div id="PosA">
  Level: <label id="level"></label>
  <br> XP: <label id="xp"></label> / <label id="levelUp"></label>
  <br>
  <br> Clicks: <label id="clicks"></label>
</div>
<div id="PosB">
  $ <label id="money"></label>
  <br> / <label id="max"></label>
</div>
```

The way you write it now is invalid in HTML (well, not really invalid, but weird stuff happens). It would be valid in XHTML but it's a dead technology and I suggest you not using it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that label element with id "level" contains the element with id "xp", "levelUp" and "clicks"

```
//document.getElementById("level")
"
        <br>
        XP: <label id=\"xp\"> / <label id=\"levelUp\">
        <br>
        <br>
        Clicks: <label id=\"clicks\">
    </label></label></label>"
```

Once you replace that with innerHTHML, element with id "xp" is not found and document.getElementById("xp") returns null.

If define the html with closing label elements it will work:

```
<div id="PosA">
    Level: <label id="level"> </label>
    <br/>
    XP: <label id="xp"> </label> / <label id="levelUp"></label> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Clicks: <label id="clicks"> </label>
</div>

<div id="PosB">
    $ <label id="money"> </label>
    <br/>
    / <label id="max"> </label>
</div>
```